# Is it possible to show xaml view inside windows form

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a windows form which calls other windows form that work within my application. What I want to accomplish is to get away from this whole "windows form" thing and use WPF View (usercontrol) instead. Is there a way I can call a view to show it from my form?

```
ElementHost host = new ElementHost();
            Cars.WPF.Views.DescriptionView descView = new Cars.WPF.Views.DescriptionView();
            host.Controls.Add(descView);
            host.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

I get error: --> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'Car.WPF.Views.DescriptionView' to 'System.Windows.Forms.Control'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a panel in your winform (lets say panel1)
Define ElementHost at class level, Also define WPF Control at class level

```
ElementHost host;
Cars.WPF.Views.DescriptionView descView;
```

In form load event do:

```
host= new ElementHost();
panel1.Controls.Add(ctrlHost); //Add Element host to panel1
descView = new Cars.WPF.Views.DescriptionView();
descView.InitializeComponent();
host.Child = descView; //Instead of adding WPF control to Winform do this
```

Also in your project references add:

```
PresentationCore
PresentationFramework
WindowsBase
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use Element Host.

http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-using-wpf-in-winforms

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx

Comment: what exacly does it not like. Does the WPF UserControl not show? Does the binding work? Keyboard input is not recongnized? Have you tried starting simple, just launching a new form with a simple WPF control? Get that to work?

Comment: what does your view have? change the background to Red, can you see it?

Comment: ah, I see, make sure your view inherits from UserControl -> public DescriptionView : UserControl